# MySQL in Node.js returning incorrect values

Tags: mysql, node.js, discord.js, node-mysql

I'm trying to write a bot for Discord which I host with Node.js. When I try to get a user id from a database by searching for the person's name I do get a result, however the id is always a bit off. For example the code

```sql
sql.query('SELECT userID FROM users WHERE name="Max"', function(error, result, fields){
    console.log(result);
});
```

returns
`[ RowDataPacket { userID: 434776574123048960 } ]` 
while the actual userID should be 4347765741230489**9**0.

I've also tried other users and found that the difference between the returned and the actual value does vary between the different users but is consistent for each user.
Inputting the SQL code directly into the mysql application does return the correct values.

Edit: Apparently js integers are a bit inaccurate after a certain length. Changing the userID type to varchar solved the issue.

Comment: You cannot directly input a query into mysql as it is a server based product. You use a different client to query mysql. Query results should be the same across multiple clients as the query results are determined by mysql, not by the client. What you need to confirm if node.js applies any data conversion on the client side.

Comment: It seems you try to store the user ID as `INT` but it should be `VARCHAR`.